# Chromaggus and fatigue

Tags: hearthstone

So Chromaggus's effect is such that every successive card that is drawn will have the player draw two copies of it.

If a player draws into fatigue with Chromaggus in play does it act as a 'card' and hence deal the same amount of damage during fatigue ( 1 and then 1) or will it draw increasing damage through fatigue (1 and then 2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Chromaggus does not cause you to take any extra fatigue damage. The wording of the card is "Whenever you draw a card, put another copy into your hand." It doesn't add extra card draws, it only duplicates the card after it is drawn.

In the official BRM reveal stream, they go into fatigue with Chromaggus on the board and only take a single fatigue hit.

Skip to minute 54 to see the play in question. http://www.twitch.tv/playhearthstone/c/6438751

Comment: Nice find! what were the odds that it was the last card..

Comment: @Tas'dingo 1 in 30, obviously :)